# I receive three different warnings in scipy integration in python

Tags: python, scipy, integral, simpsons-rule

I have the code structure below. I would like to get some numerical results here.

```
import numpy as np
import scipy
from scipy import integrate

alpha = .99
t = np.linspace(0, .85, 5)
s = np.empty_like(t)
f = np.power(t - s, -alpha)
Int = integrate.simpson(f, s)
Int
```

I got the warnings below. I understand that the first term in `t`, that is `t[0]` causes the errors, particularly first two warnings. But I do not know how I can avoid these warnings. I cannot change the `alpha`,`t` or `f`.

```
<ipython-input-1-6b0d0757bfac>:8: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in power
  f = np.power(t-s, -alpha)
/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/scipy/integrate/_quadrature.py:414: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in true_divide
  h0divh1 = h0 / h1
/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/scipy/integrate/_quadrature.py:416: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in true_divide
  y[slice1] * (hsum * hsum / hprod) +
nan
```

I tried to take `t = np.linspace(1e-8, .85, 5)`. It did not work.

**EDIT:** The `t` is stable. I cannot change it. I need to derive `s` from `t` or find a new definition for `s`. So, I have

```
t = np.linspace(0, .85, 5)
array([0.    , 0.2125, 0.425 , 0.6375, 0.85  ])
```

Let us take the `s` as an array of zeros (array of ones also does not work for `s`)

```
s = np.zeros_like(t)
array([0., 0., 0., 0., 0.])
```

and add `1` to `f` to avoid the warning of `RuntimeWarning: divide by zero encountered in power`

```
f = (t1+1-s)** -.99
array([1.        , 0.82633295, 0.70424421, 0.61370619, 0.54387612])
```

After this when I used the `simpson`, it gives `nan`.

```
Int = integrate.simpson(f, s)
nan
```

Depending on the definition of `s`, I am constantly encountering a warning or an error .

**The question is: What could be the right definition of `s` along with the `t` defined above?**

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with that `s` array?

Comment: did you look at `s`?  or `f` before calling `simpson`?

Comment: @hpaulj I have used `np.isfinite(f)`and it gave `False`.  And `np.isfinite(s)` gave `True`. What did you mean by -did you look at-? Do I need to use another method to look at them? Thank you.

Comment: @hpaulj Oh `print(s)` also gives `nan` values as mentioned in Alexs answer. I was thinking `s` just an empty array and I aimed to overwrite it.

Comment: But  you didn't overwrite it; you used it in `f` as is!  Don't use `np.empty` unless you actually understand what it does.  `np.zeros` is safer.  `f` is an array, not a function.  With other integrate functions you supply a function, for this you supply an array.

Comment: I wrote an answer showing the actual `s` and `f` produced by your code (at least for one run), and hopefully showed that this setup doesn't make sense.  I won't suggest an fix, since I don't know what integral you are trying to calculate.

Comment: Also, you may notice that those are three warnings: you can only ever get one error, since that would imply a crash

Answer (score 0):

There is an issue when you are using `s` because you created it like this:

```
s = np.empty_like(t)
```

What you are doing here is creating an array that has the same properties as `t` but is uninitialised, meaning that its shape and type are the same as `t` but its values are not set (thus "random").

For example, when I print `s` I have:

```
array([inf, nan, nan, nan, nan])
```

And you could have basically any values here.

So, you need to provide values to s before using it.

If you want to initialise s to zeros, you should replace that line by:

```
s = np.zeros_like(t)
```

Comment: Thank you for this enlightening information.

Answer (score 0):

Your first lines, and the results.  With a size of 5, there's not excuse to not look at the arrays in full.  No summary needed.

```
In [80]: alpha = .99
    ...: t = np.linspace(0, .85, 5)
    ...: s = np.empty_like(t)
    ...: f = np.power(t - s, -alpha)
C:\Users\paul\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_2648\1323274646.py:4: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in power
  f = np.power(t - s, -alpha)
```

5 equally space numbers:

```
In [81]: t
Out[81]: array([0.    , 0.2125, 0.425 , 0.6375, 0.85  ])
```

5 values as well; with `empty` they aren't predictable.  sometimes I see 0s,  but the is a good example of ridiculous "random" values.  We don't want to use the `s` as is; it has to overwritten with something:

```
In [82]: s
Out[82]: 
array([6.36598737e-314, 1.90979621e-313, 8.48798317e-314, 1.69759663e-313,
       1.27319747e-313])

In [83]: f
Out[83]: array([       nan, 4.63355855, 2.33289375, 1.56158135, 1.17456015]
```

And the term that produced the **warning** (not error):

```
In [89]: (t[0]-s[0])
Out[89]: -6.365987374e-314
In [90]: (t[0]-s[0])**-.99
C:\Users\paul\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_2648\147715877.py:1: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in double_scalars
  (t[0]-s[0])**-.99
Out[90]: nan
```

Ekaba's suggestion:

```
In [91]: alpha = .99
    ...: t = np.linspace(0, .85, 5)
    ...: s = np.empty_like(t)
    ...: f = np.empty_like(t)
    ...: 
    ...: for i in range(1, len(t)):
    ...:     s[i] = t[i-1]
    ...:     f[i] = (t[i] - s[i])**(-alpha)
    ...:
```

This overwrites `s` and `f`, but I'm not sure those are useful.

same 5 term `t`:

```
In [92]: t
Out[92]: array([0.    , 0.2125, 0.425 , 0.6375, 0.85  ])
```

`s` is now just `t` values, offset by 1.  The first is still "random":

```
In [93]: s
Out[93]: 
array([-6.36598737e-314,  0.00000000e+000,  2.12500000e-001,
        4.25000000e-001,  6.37500000e-001])
```

And for `f`, again ignoring the first, the rest as the same:

```
In [94]: f
Out[94]: 
array([2.12199579e-314, 4.63355855e+000, 4.63355855e+000, 4.63355855e+000,
       4.63355855e+000])
```

The successive differences of `t` raised to `-alpha`:

```
In [96]: np.diff(t)
Out[96]: array([0.2125, 0.2125, 0.2125, 0.2125])    
In [97]: np.diff(t)**-.99
Out[97]: array([4.63355855, 4.63355855, 4.63355855, 4.63355855])
```

The integral is the area of a rectangle `f[-1]` high, and `s[-1]` wide:

```
In [104]: f[-1]*s[-1]
Out[104]: 2.953893574179393
```

I'm guessing the OP thought that he defined `f` as a function, that, `simpson` was going to pass successive values of `s` to it.  Other `integrate` functions do take a function (e.g. `quad`), but this takes an array.

## Simpson example

Here's an example that may be similar to what you want:

Specify an array of sample points:

```
In [109]: x = np.linspace(0,1,11)
```

and a `t` and `f`.  Both are calculated from `x`.  `t` adds a 1 to avoid the `x=0` problem:

```
In [110]: t = (x+1)**2    
In [111]: f = (t-x)**-.99
```

Displaying the values:

```
In [112]: x,t,f
Out[112]: 
(array([0. , 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9, 1. ]),
 array([1.  , 1.21, 1.44, 1.69, 1.96, 2.25, 2.56, 2.89, 3.24, 3.61, 4.  ]),
 array([1.        , 0.90184157, 0.80818825, 0.72179746, 0.64388254,
        0.57463534, 0.51364905, 0.46021453, 0.41350815, 0.37270087,
        0.33701556]))
```

And the simpson integration:

```
In [113]: simpson(f,x)
Out[113]: 0.6073410199915571
```

Without plotting (or using `sympy`) I can only estimate whether that makes sense.  The area under a curve that starts at 1 and decresses to .3, over the `x` range of 0 to 1 - `.6` is a reasonable value.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. I am not looking for an area of `f[-1]*s[-1]`. It is clear that, I have been trying to calculate integrand `f`, that is, `f=(t-s)**(-alpha)` with respect to `s` (variable of the integration is `ds`) along with the `t`-dependent integration limits. On the other hand, since `t` is an array, `simpson` seems like a right choice for this calculation. I am not so sure, but I guess defining the `s` correctly is the source of the problem here.

Comment: I added a simpson example that is somewhat like what you describe.

Comment: Thank you, it was a helpful example. But you defined `x` and derived `t` from it. I have `t` and I need to derive `x` from `t` or make a new definition. I made an edit to the post about this issue. You can have an idea about the problem I encountered.

Comment: `t` is just an array.  What's it's relation to the integration variable (`x` in my example, `s` in yours)? I don't give `simpson` `t`, I give it `f`.  Abstractly, I am integrating `f(x)` over a range of values defined by `x`.  `simpson` is used where that `f(x)` is defined for a discrete set of `x` values.  `quad` can be used when `f` is a continuous function, that can be evaluated at any `x` in the range.  In my example, `t` could have been pulled out of the air, but it still has to have one value for each `x` value.  The real goal is to construct `f`, as array or function.

Comment: This is the point where I am stuck. What is the relationship between `t` and `s`? When expressing `s` in code, should a relationship be established between `t` and `s`, or should `s` be defined independently? If so, how should it be defined?

Comment: Forget about `t` for the moment.  What is `f(x)`, the function that you want to integrate.  Imagine for example, a graph with `x` values horizontally (between say 0 and 1).  What are `y` axis values; the line that you plot?  The integral is the area under that curve.  It may help to imagine `t(x)`, as a continuous curve (or may piecewise linear).  Defining the integration function is your job, not ours.

Comment: Someone else using `simpson`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75586614/different-results-when-computing-integral-analytically-with-scipy-vs-approximati

Comment: I was able to eliminate warnings and the error with a custom `s` definition. As I code the rest of my equation, I'll watch it to see if my choice for `s` is correct. Your explanations helped me a lot. Thank you.